# get function names from a list python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that will print the values of a object but only those values that are defined in a list.

```
import boto.ec2.cloudwatch
conn = boto.ec2.cloudwatch.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-1')
alarms = conn.describe_alarms()
for alarm in alarms:
    print alarm.name
```

this will return a particular value for all alarms. How ever I want to make it work in such a way that I am able to print all the values that are defined in a list. Here is what I am trying to do

```
import boto.ec2.cloudwatch
conn = boto.ec2.cloudwatch.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-1')
alarms = conn.describe_alarms()
whitelist = ["name", "metric", "namespace"]
for alarm in alarms:
    print alarm.whitelist[0]
```

However this wont works of course. Any suggestion about what will be the best way to do that? SO that I am able to print everything that is defined in a whitelist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) (note that you are referring to *attributes*, or possibly *methods*, not *functions*):

```
for alarm in alarms:
    for attr in whitelist:
        print getattr(alarm, attr)
```

`getattr` takes an optional third argument, the default value in case `attr` isn't found, so you could do e.g.:

```
for attr in whitelist:
    print "{0}: {1}".format(attr, getattr(alarm, attr, "<Not defined>"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`getattr()` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr).

Your code would looks something like this:

```
import boto.ec2.cloudwatch
conn = boto.ec2.cloudwatch.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-1')
alarms = conn.describe_alarms()
whitelist = ["name", "metric", "namespace"]
for alarm in alarms:
    for attribute in whitelist:
        print(getattr(alarm, attribute))
```